# Populate HTML5 local storage with remote JSON

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

Im trying to make a simple CRUD phone directory webapp where users can download a small telephone directory (say for a company) from a webserver (when online) to the app, and then make their own editions to this by CRUD (including when offline). I’m just learning so im not really interested (at this stage) in syncing these changes back to the server.

I found this very useful tutorial on how to use HTML5 local storage and JS to make a CRUD database:

http://mrbool.com/creating-a-crud-form-with-html5-local-storage-and-json/26719

However, I can’t work how to first populate this database with JSON data downloaded from a webserver.

The idea is that the user can select their company (say from a dropdown list) when online, and download the JSON of the telephone directory to the local storage database which they can then edit locally.

If anybody can help point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.
Thanks

Comment: What problem are you having? Parsing remote JSON? Getting the remote data in the first place? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

In order to save objects in localStorage or sessionStorage, the objects need to be turned into strings.  And then when you retrieve the data, turn it back into an object.

Here are two prototypes I wrote to do this:

```
Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
  this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
  var value = this.getItem(key);
  if (value == undefined) return [] ;
  return value && JSON.parse(value);
}
```

Usage:

```
var obj1 = {a:234, b:456};
localStorage.setObject('obj1', obj1);

console.log(localStorage)    // it's in there


var obj2 = localStorage.getObject('obj1');
console.log(obj2)           // got it back
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at store.js.  It's pretty simple and it abstracts away parsing JSON or stringifying it.

https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/

Here's an example usage

```
// Store 'marcus' at 'username'
store.set('username', 'marcus')

// Get 'username'
store.get('username')

// Remove 'username'
store.remove('username')

// Clear all keys
store.clear()

// Store an object literal - store.js uses JSON.stringify under the hood
store.set('user', { name: 'marcus', likes: 'javascript' })

// Get the stored object - store.js uses JSON.parse under the hood
var user = store.get('user')
alert(user.name + ' likes ' + user.likes)

// Get all stored values
store.getAll().user.name == 'marcus'

// Loop over all stored values
store.forEach(function(key, val) {
    console.log(key, '==', val)
})
```